# Anyone seen this error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Premier.Global" Language="C#" %>

Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

One more thing. Whenever I try to install the System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll using gacutil command line tool it fails.

Comment: Yep.  All you have to do is google it and you'll find tons of instances.  There are several possible causes and accordingly, several possible resolutions.

Comment: David, I have but all of them do not have this issue with Wrapper.dll and that's why i came here to Stack Overfow. I suspect this has to do with the latest security update to .NET 3.5.1 and .NET 4 (KB 2686831, KB 2656373 and KB 2686827 , KB 2656368 respectively)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure IIS is set to 'Enable 32 bit applications' in your particular application pool, if you use IIS

Make sure your project build properties are set to "Any CPU" in Visual Studio, if you use Visual Studio

Comment: Hi Arran i get this error when i am running the project in Visual Studio 2010 .NET 4. I checked the project property its set to Any CPU.

Comment: Close VS, delete your entire debug, bin, obj, and release folders for your project, and rebuild - have you tried that?

Comment: I just did. I closed VS, cleared the debug folder, and opened VS rebuilt each individual project and it still came up with same error.

Answer (score 2):

The project finally worked after I downloaded and installed updates for .NET framework 4.0 i.e. 4.0.3 + some other updates i listed below:

[Microsoft .NET Framework 4 KB2468871](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3556)

[Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Reliability Update 1 (KB2533523)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27014)

[Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Reliability Update 2 (KB2600217)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28936)

[Update 4.0.3 for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 – Runtime Update (KB2600211)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29053)

I did this after noticing the difference between version info of .NET framework and that of ASP.NET below the error on my page i.e. .272

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

Thanks again for listening.

Comment: I had a similar issue and just installing update 4.0.3 fixed it for me.